# call external html template for kendo grid column template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been trying for a long time to get this to work..

Basically I am assigning columns and templates dynamically to the kendo grid. Each column can be of any type. If the type is 'address' type, then I am assigning a html template to that column to split the address string and display in a nice way.

I am doing this by creating a map of possible column types and their corresponding templates. The problem is with 'address' map.

```
 uiTemplateMap["date"] = "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(" + fieldName + "), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #";
 uiTemplateMap["address"] = eval("kendo.template($('\\#address-template').html())");
```

The 'address-template' is defined as

```
 <script id="address-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # var addr =  ${addresses} ; #
    # var splitaddr = addr.split(','); #
    # for (int i=0; i < splitaddr.length(); i++) { #
        <i> #= splitaddr[i] # </i>
    # } #
 </script>
```

I get a invalid template exception. I have two questions.

1. how can I assign a column value to a javascript variable? The ${addresses} assignment does not seem to work.
2. I dont want to hard-code the 'addresses' column in the template. Can I pass the column name or value to the template like $('#address-template').html(columnName) ??

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the column value in `data[columnName]` where `columnName` is the field's name (a string), or, because the template function is using a `with` block, simply in `columnName`, so you could define a template generator like this:

```
function createAddressTemplateFor(columnName) {
    return "# var address = data['" + columnName + "']; #" + // or: var address = columnName;
        "# var splitaddr = address.split(','); #" +
        "# for (var i = 0; i < splitaddr.length; i++) { #" +
        "<i> #= splitaddr[i] # </i><br />" +
        "# } #";
}
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/VCU2G/))

If you want to use external templates, you'll probably have to hardcode the names (since the property name of the current column is not passed to the template), unless you want to modify the Kendo UI source code.